# How to Catch Timed Out Exception

Tags: java, multithreading

Code :

```
Class Manager {
    Future  fu  = pool.invokeAll(workers, SEARCH_TIMEOUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    // calling the invoke call 
    search search= fu.get();    
   // callable 
}


public class Search implements Callable<Search> {
    Search call() {
        // multiple workers will execute Code So don't want to catch timed out exception in here 
        // api value will be changing based on corresponding reference 
        api.search_api();
    }
}


class api()
{
    search_api(){
        // How to catch a timed out exception in here 
        // catch(TimedoutException){}    did not work in here 
    }
}
```

Is there a way that I can catch the TimedOut exception in the Class api under method `search_api()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch [TimeoutException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeoutException.html)  like this code :

```
try {
        Future fu = pool.invokeAll(workers, SEARCH_TIMEOUT,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        // calling the invoke call
        search search = fu.get();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it by the following way

```
try{

.

.

.

.


catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
}
```